# A man sells ﬁrewood. To make standard portions, he uses a standard length of rope $l$ to surround a pack of logs

Tags: geometry

> A man sells ﬁrewood. To make standard portions, he uses a standard length of rope $l$ to surround a pack of logs. One day, a customer asks him for a double portion of ﬁrewood. What length of rope should he use to measure this order? Assume the packs of logs are circular in shape.

This is a typical order:

[image]

$l$ is equal to $2\pi r$

This is the new order:
[image]

I understand that the perimeter in this case is:

The two sides A, plus the two half-circles, A = $2r$

$4r + 2\pi r$

However, the answer is $\sqrt{2}l$.

How can I get to this result?

Comment: Does a double portion mean two circles or a bigger circle? The problem says "double portion" not double order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A double portion bundled with a circular cross section has area $2\pi r^2$ where $r$ is the radius of a standard portion.

A circle with twice the area $2\pi r^2$ has radius $R$ such that $\pi R^2=2\pi r^2$ which gives us that $R=\sqrt{2}r$.

A rope that ties the standard portion has length equal to the circumference of the circle and is equal to $2\pi r$. For the larger circle the rope has to be $$2\pi R=2\pi\sqrt{2}r=\sqrt{2}l$$

Answer (score 1):

I would think you need to find the circumference of a disk with twice the area, right? That is, find $$2\pi r_2$$ given that that $$\pi r_2^2 =2\cdot \pi r^2$$